# Compile time error when styling BaseView like LoadingDecorator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, prism

For instance I have the next code for my BaseView:

```
using System.Windows;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Core;

namespace Infrastructure.BaseView
{
    public class BaseView : LoadingDecorator
    {
        public BaseView()
        {
            Style = FindResource("BaseViewStyle") as Style;
        }
    }
}
```

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type baseView:BaseView}" x:Key="BaseViewStyle" >
    <Setter Property="OwnerLock" Value="InputOnly"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=baseViewModel:BaseViewModel}">
            <DataTrigger.Value>
                <enums:ViewState>Busy</enums:ViewState>
            </DataTrigger.Value>
            <Setter Property="IsSplashScreenShown" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=baseViewModel:BaseViewModel}">
            <DataTrigger.Value>
                <enums:ViewState>Default</enums:ViewState>
            </DataTrigger.Value>
            <Setter Property="IsSplashScreenShown" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then I create specific view like this(name space definition is not so simple because view has really complex UI):

```
<baseView:BaseView x:Class="General.Views.ProjectListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:baseView="clr-namespace:Infrastructure.BaseView;assembly=Infrastructure"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:General.ViewModels"
         xmlns:dxprg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/propertygrid"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
         xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1000" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:ProjectListViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
         x:Name="View"
...
</baseView:BaseView>
```

In run time everything works perfect, but I have a compile time error:

> Error 4   Cannot create an instance of "BaseView".

And Designer in my VS does not work. And in it's StackTrace I can watch next information

> at System.Windows.Style.CheckTargetType(Object element)
>
> at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
>
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>
> ...

I realized that the problem in `TargetType="{x:Type baseView:BaseView}"` in my style, but without this code my style shows me errors and not works and I understand it.

**How can I remove this compile time error?**
It is ok to use `LoadingDecorator` for BaseView? I think that if I have some views in display and some of its can be busy, some - not. So, I thought to do it will be good.

I use PRISM in my app and I thought to take out `LoadingDecorator` in `Shell.xaml` beyond every regions but in this case I don't understand how can I bind `IsSplashScreenShown` to specific ViewModel of specific View.

Comment: And it appears only after **rebuilding**

Comment: The error in my [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696822/a-value-of-type-popupwindowaction-cannot-be-added-to-a-collection-or-dictionar?noredirect=1#comment53322727_32696822) has the same behavior. It some times apperares some times - not. Some times relaunch and rebuild helps, some times - not! It's a bad magic and I don't understand the reason of it =(