# A value of type 'PopupWindowAction' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

Refer to [Prism manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921081(v=pandp.40).aspx) I made my modal view and pasted it in main view like this:

```
<baseView:BaseView ... >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding DocumentSelectionRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <modal:DocumentSelectionView />
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
...
</Grid>
</baseView:BaseView>
```

But I have got the **compile time** error in `<prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True">` (in run time everything is perfect):

> Error  3   A value of type 'PopupWindowAction' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'.

In my project I use PRISM 5 and .NET 4.5

**UDP:**

Namespaces are defined (in `baseView:BaseView`) like:

```
xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

References:

> Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity Version 5.0.0.0
>
> System.Windows.Interactivity Version 4.5.0.0

Comment: did you try cleaning & rebuilding the solution?

Comment: it doesnt show any such error for me in compile time too !

Comment: @Nikita, I've added UDP, please check it

Comment: I have the same references.

Comment: This is all IntelliSense crap. Have you tried to clean up your solution followed by closing Visual Studio and rebuilding all the code again?

Comment: @dymanoid, yes, I've done it! A lot of times. And some times this error hides some times appears. And I don't understand why? What the trigger for this error.
My post about [BaseView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695109/compile-time-error-when-styling-baseview-like-loadingdecorator) has the same behaviour.
I can relaunch VS and rebuild APP and some times it helps me (some times - not!), but then after 1-2 hours of codding error can appear again(can - not!). It's a magic)))

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio 2015? I was having a similar problem with VS 2015, but not in VS 2013, and I first thought something was wrong with the binaries from the Prism framework. I posted an issue on the Prism GitHub:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/213

The thing that worked for me, eventually, was reinstalling VS 2015. I suspect that some of the optional extensions/plugins for VS 2015 was causing the problem. Hopefully this will solve your troubles too.